# Covert money character to numeric in R

Tags: r, dataframe, currency

I have this dataset which has money in character format with a pound sign and "m" for million after it. I am trying to do some calculations with the numbers so need them in numeric format not character format.

This is the first row of the original dataframe

```
   Item     Money_In    total_bought  Money_Out  total_sold  Net_Spend
1  unit1    £192.60m    15            £64.78m    13          £-127.82m
```

I am trying to make the output table this:

```
   Item     Money_In    total_bought  Money_Out  total_sold  Net_Spend
1  unit1    192600000   15            64780000   13          -127820000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base R` solution:

You are creating a function that does the following:
- removes the first and last characters of `x`
- converts the vector `x` to numeric class
- multiplies `x` by 1,000,000

Then you call the function on each of the variables that you'd like to change.

```
rm_pound_func <- function(x){
  x <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x)-1)
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x <- x * 1000000
}

df$Money_In <- rm_pound_func(df$Money_In)
df$Money_Out <- rm_pound_func(df$Money_Out)
df$Net_Spend <- rm_pound_func(df$Net_Spend)
```

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

There's probably a more elegant way of doing this, but it still works.

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Money_In, Money_Out, Net_Spend),
            list( ~ str_sub(., 2, -2))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Money_In, Money_Out, Net_Spend),
            list(as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Money_In, Money_Out, Net_Spend),
            list(~. * 1000000))
```

Both methods give us:

```
 Item   Money_In total_bought Money_Out total_sold  Net_Spend
  <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 unit1 192600000           15  64780000         13 -127820000
```

dput:

```
df <- structure(list(Item = "unit1", Money_In = "£192.60m", total_bought = 15, 
    Money_Out = "£64.78m", total_sold = 13, Net_Spend = "£-127.82m"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you need to extend this solution for k for example

```
library(tidyverse)
example_df <- data.table::fread("   Item     Money_In    total_bought  Money_Out  total_sold  Net_Spend
  unit1    £192.60m    15            £64.78m    13          £-127.82m") 

unmoney_mi <- function(x){
  x %>% 
    str_remove("£") %>% 
    str_remove("m") %>% 
    as.numeric() * 10 ^ 6
}

unmoney <- function(x){
  if (x %>% str_detect("m")) {
    unmoney_mi(x)
  } else {
    x
  }
}

example_df %>% mutate_all(unmoney)
```